# Does an automatic "print locals" command exist in gdb?

Tags: c++, c, printing, gdb

Is there a gdb command that does what `info locals` does but **automatically** (i.e after every step or breakpoint)? I find info locals to be very essential, but I would much rather not have to type it everytime. It would be a bummer if something like that is not implemented.

Also I'm not looking to "watch" or "display" a specific variable or two. Display all, everytime, that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

> Display all, everytime, that's what I'm looking for.

```
(gdb) define hook-stop
info locals
end
```

Example:

```
// foo.c
int foo()
{
  int z = 1;
  int zz = 2;
  int zzz = 3;
  return z + zz + zzz;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 42;
  int y = 24;
  foo();
  return x;
}

gcc -g foo.c && gdb -q ./a.out

(gdb) define hook-stop
Type commands for definition of "hook-stop".
End with a line saying just "end".
>info locals
>end
(gdb) start

Temporary breakpoint 1 at 0x1159: file foo.c, line 11.
Starting program: /tmp/a.out
x = 0
y = 0

Temporary breakpoint 1, main () at foo.c:11
11        int x = 42;
(gdb) n
x = 42
y = 0
12        int y = 24;
(gdb) n
x = 42
y = 24
13        foo();
(gdb) s
z = 21845
zz = 1431654784
zzz = 0
foo () at foo.c:3
3         int z = 1;
(gdb) n
z = 1
zz = 1431654784
zzz = 0
4         int zz = 2;
(gdb) n
z = 1
zz = 2
zzz = 0
5         int zzz = 3;
(gdb) n
z = 1
zz = 2
zzz = 3
6         return z + zz + zzz;
(gdb) n
z = 1
zz = 2
zzz = 3
7       }
(gdb)
x = 42
y = 24
main () at foo.c:14
14        return x;
(gdb) q
```

Documentation [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Hooks.html).